# Having trouble running a function run asynchronously or as background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, async-await

I'm trying to create an application that launches the GUI then AFTER it's already shown I want it to run another function that uses WebClient() and once it does it's query it's supposed to output to a label on the page. I've tried using on shown and a few other events but all of them stop the GUI from loading before it's finished making the query.

I've tried using a thread and it wouldn't allow updating the label since it was on a different thread, I tried async but couldn't manage to get results for some reason and now i'm in the middle of trying a background worker and I'm not getting any errors but the labels aren't getting updated either.

right now I have something that looks like this

```
public project()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += querysite;
    }

    private void querysite(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "libcurl-agent/1.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData("http://example.com/SystemStatus");
        string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
        if (download.IndexOf("is online") !=-1)
        {
            systemStatusLabel.Text = "System is up";
        }
        else
        {
            systemStatusLabel.Text = "System is down!";
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this? I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and can't find anything that does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit, to work with a `BackgroundWorker`.
I have also allowed myself to do a bit of separation between the logic action of quering the site, and updating the GUI.
This should work for you:

```
    public project()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
        bool isOnline = false;
        bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {

            //what happens here must not touch the form
            //as it's in a different thread
            isOnline = querysite();


        };

        bw.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //update progress bars here

        };

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //now you're back in the UI thread you can update the form

            if (isOnline)
            {
                systemStatusLabel.Text = "System is up";
            }
            else
            {
                systemStatusLabel.Text = "System is down!";
            }


        }; 

    }

    private bool querysite()
    {
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "libcurl-agent/1.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData("http://example.com/SystemStatus");
        string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
        bool isOnline = download.IndexOf("is online") != -1;
        return isOnline;            

    }
```

When you want the query to be done, you need to call `bw.RunWorkerAsync();`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, got a bitch confused at first cause I wasn't able to call bw.RunWorkerAsync(); from within the on shown event of the form for some reason but I placed it right after it's declaration and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update something on the UI thread from a different thread, that won't work out. You can create a delegate to update the text though, this is a simple way to accomplish that.

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { systemStatusLabel.Text = "System is up"; });
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm just getting into C# and you didn't specify any details on like where would I call this? and how would I send the update to it?

Comment: Avi's answer is much more complete and a much better way of designing something, I'd go with that approach. But, for the sake of completeness... If you needed to update something on the main UI thread from another thread, rather than just writing something like `label1.Text = "Test";` (which will fail) you could use the above code, which will create a delegate which runs on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

[The asynchronous programming model with `async` and `await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) provides and easy to understand and maintain way of coding.

There's no need for another asynchronous work manager (like the `BackgroundWorker`) ohter than what's provided byt the language and conforming APIs.

Supposing some UI event is triggering the start of the work, all you have to do is:

```
private async void MyEvent(object sender, EventHandler e)
{
    systemStatusLabel.Text = await GetSystemStatusAsync();
}

private async Task<string> GetSystemStatusAsync()
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "libcurl-agent/1.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    var myDataBuffer = await myWebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://example.com/SystemStatus");
    string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
    if (download.IndexOf("is online") !=-1)
    {
        return "System is up";
    }
    else
    {
        return "System is down!";
    }
}
```

Altough the new **TaskAsync** suffixed methods of the `WebClient` conform to this new way of coding, I would recommend you to use the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) which was developed with this new way of coding in mind.

Comment: Well the reason I am focusing on WebClient vs HttpClient is the response time for HttpClient (async) is almost 50 times slower than WebClient (sync). The less than 1 second response from WebClient appeals to me much more than the up to 10 seconds HttpClient (async) or ~7 second HttpClient (sync). I will however look into trying the async method cause my first attempt confused me.

Comment: Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) to see if the HTTP communication is the same? In the end it's just a pair of `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` instances at work.

Comment: I have not, that's interesting though. I don't know exactly why it's slower I know that results have found that and didn't want to spend too much time looking into why exactly, just wanted the results.